# PYTHON как вызвать другую функцию при работающей функции (с планировшиком модуль: schedule)

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть две функции: одна функция работает по расписанию (каждые 3 секунды допустим),
но есть еше другая(или много других функций), которые я хочу запустить, но вот что то не допонимаю. Планировшик(schedule) блокирует работу остального кода. **Планировщик в идеале должен будет запускать некий процесс по нажатии кнопки допустим, но при этом не должен блокировать остальной код програмы !!!**

```
import schedule
import time

def test():             # простая функция вывод инфы
    a = 1
    z = a + 2
    print(z)

def job():               # функция с планировщиком (каждые три секунды запускается)
    print("I'm working on")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)

def run_primer():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


run_primer()    # вызываем фунцию с планировщиком

test()          # вызов другой функции ??? НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ЕЁ ВЫЗВАТЬ/запустить
```

Comment: вроде начинаю понимать нужно в отдельном потоке запустить

Comment: Ты эта пиши если что.

Comment: хорошо :)       распишу свой ответ